# What's the shortest command to find a volume's BSD device name ( /dev/disk*s* )?

Tags: mac-osx, unix, command-line-interface, bsd

**What's the easiest way to find out that, for example,** /Volumes/Foo **lives in** /dev/disk0s2 **?**

EDIT: ***mount*** is probably a more semantically satisfying answer, but it doesn't get much shorter than ***df***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or df -h, which will show usage as well.
diskutil list will show available disks.

Comment: Works fine just as "df" for this purpose

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
mount
```

Answer (score 2):

alias a letter to....
than you'll have one letter command

Comment: +1, actually a pretty decent answer.